# fill combobox in windows form application C# with time interval (hours: minutes)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, combobox

hello I have a combobox in my windows form application C#

How can I fill it with time from a specific start time (for example 12:00) to a specific end time (for example 14:00) by adding 20 minutes, just like in the following picture:

[image: fill combobox with time]

Comment: Where is the problem?

Comment: WPF or Windows Forms?... have you tried something?

Comment: i don't know how to fill it  like that

Comment: You need to create a datasource containing your times and bind them to the drop down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do it using a simple while loop:

```
var item = DateTime.Today.AddHours(14); // 14:00:00
while(item <= DateTime.Today.AddHours(16)) // 16:00:00
{
    cmb.Items.Add(item.TimeOfDay.ToString(@"hh\:mm"));
    item = item.AddMinutes(20);
}
```

Comment: bro is there a way to fill it like that too, 12:00 then 13:00 then 14:00 ... 16:00

Comment: Sure, just use `AddHours(1)` instead of `AddMinutes(20)`.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume that you want some flexibility in the first and last hours but you are sure that your intervals will always be 20 minutes.

**If** it's ok for you to have your times represented as simple strings, you can use two nested loops:

```
const int firstHour = 12;
const int lastHour = 14;
for (var hour = firstHour; hour < lastHour; hour++)
{
    for (var minute = 0; minute <= 40; minute += 20)
    {
        comboBox.Items.Add($"{hour}:{minute:00}");
    }
}
comboBox.Items.Add($"{lastHour}:00");
```

**If** you want your times as instances of DateTime instead, use this loop:

```
const int firstHour = 12;
const int lastHour = 14;
var time = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, firstHour, 0, 0); //or any other suitable year,month,day
while (time.Hour < lastHour)
{
    comboBox.Items.Add(time);
    time = time.AddMinutes(20);
}
comboBox.Items.Add(new DateTime(time.Year, time.Month, time.Day, lastHour, 0, 0));
comboBox.FormatString = "HH:mm"; //to prevent the date from being displayed
```

I defined `firstHour` and `lastHour` as constants to keep the examples simple, you can turn them into variables, arguments for a method, or whatever is more useful for you.